# Why nth-child does not apply style to the element in NUXTJS

Tags: css, nuxtjs

```
<b-card>
    <b-img :src="history.featured_image.data.thumbnails[6].url"></b-img>
</b-card>

<style scoped>
.card img:nth-child(odd) {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
</style>
```

I was testing out the nth-child, it either ignore the nth-child and apply to all the img or does nothing
I tried .card img:nth-child(1) it applied to every img but when I do nth-child(2) it doesn't work.
Does css selector work in NUXTJS?
Just started with NUXTJS. I need some help. Thank you